# Expo background Location not working in background

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

The background service works perfectly in the foreground but when the app is in the background, stops sending the location updated.

this mostly happens when the app is in production, here more details:

this is the task:

```
TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, async ({ data, error }) => {
  console.log("Entro a este task")
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
      // Error occurred - check `error.message` for more details.
      return;
    }
    if (data) {
      const { locations } = data;
      console.log(locations)

      let getLastTime = await AsyncStorage.getItem('lastTime');
    console.log(getLastTime)

      if(getLastTime){

        let timeInterval = moment(new Date()).diff(getLastTime,'seconds')

        if(timeInterval<=10) {
          return
        }
        
        console.log(timeInterval)
        console.log("Este es el intervalo")
      }

     await LocationAPI.sendCurrentLocation(locations[0].coords).then(async res=>{
        console.log(res)
        console.log("Se envio")
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('lastTime',  new Date().toString())


      }).catch(err=>{

        alert(err.message)
      })


   
      // do something with the locations captured in the background
    }
  });
```

this is the function that calls this task:

```
        const { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
        if (status === "granted") {
          await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, {
            accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
            showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: true,
      
          
            activityType: Location.ActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation,
            foregroundService: {
              notificationTitle: "Tienes una orden activa",
              notificationBody: "Entregando pedido...",
              notificationColor: "#RRGGBB",
            },
          });
        }
```

Comment: Hi. Did you eventually mange to solve this?

Comment: Yes, I was using sdk38. 
The code was working perfectly. The problem was my environment. I had to reinstall expo and erase the expo cache to have this worked in development.

But in production was always working.

Comment: Awesome. glad to hear. Thanks a lot for responding.